# Dynamic SlotDuration in TimeLine View of RadScheduler

Tags: asp.net, telerik

In RadScheduler [TimeLine View], I have a StartDate = 1st Jan 2014 and EndDate = 30th April 2014 [both inclusive] and I have set the SlotDuration = 31 days.

I need to display 4 (January, February, March, April) slots [i.e. Number Of Slots = no of months between StartDate and EndDate taking above Dates into consideration] in TimeLine View and SlotDuration for each slot needs to be no. of days present in that month.

For January, SlotDuration = 31 [because January has 31 days]
    February, SlotDuration = 28 [because February has 28 days or 29 if it's a Leap Year]
    March, SlotDuration = 31 [because March has 31 days]
    April, SlotDuration = 30 [because April has 30 days]

Case 1:
    When I plot an appointment from 1 March 2014 to 31 March 2014, it should start and end in March slot but it starts from February slot because we have set SlotDuration = 31 days and February 2014 has only 28 days. 
To fulfill 31 days slot duration, 1st, 2nd and 3rd of March are pushed to February 2014 slot.

Case 2:
    When I plot an appointment from 4 March 2014 to 31 March 2014 it starts from March slot which is correct. But March slot also contains 1st, 2nd, and 3rd of April to fulfill 31 days slot duration.

My question is how do I make SlotDuration dynamic for each slot?

Currently, For Case 1 RadScheduler displays my appointment like in TimeLineMonth_Incorrect.png but i want to display it as in TimeLineMonth_Correct.png

[image: TimeLineMonth_Incorrect]

[image: TimeLineMonth_Correct]